# Removing ListView after user selects item

Tags: android, listview, visibility

This one should be pretty simple.  The use case is that I have a ListView generated by the results of a voice search.  Once the user selects the appropriate item from the list, I want the list to disappear.  This list (its contents) will not be needed again.  I know this can be done in a number of ways, but I am not experienced enough to know which is best (quickest, most efficient with mobile resources...etc.)  I have used clearChoices(), setVisibility(2) 'Gone'.  Anyway I thought I would go to the source for a proper answer.

Thanks as always for your help.  Here is the relevant code, if you like:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));

        mList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String description = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                final EditText etDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditDescription);

                etDesc.setText(description);
                mList.setVisibility(2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know exactly what is what you are trying to accomplish.
You can solve this by creating a `Dialog` containing the list, and you can either dismiss the `Dialog` as soon as they press the item, or you can do it with an "Ok" button.

Also you can separate your `activity` into two, and whenever the item is selected from the list, you finish the `activity` and go back to the previous `activity`.

Another solution, is that once the item is selected then you do `mList.setVisibility(View.Gone)` (or `View.Invisible` depending on what you want to accomplish).

Any of these solutions can work, and you would have to decide what works best for the logic of your app.
I hope that helps

Comment: thanks Raukodraug.  At this point I was just looking for the best way to make the existing ListView invisible... the thing I was missing was the (View.GONE).  Thanks very much for that!  In the end I will probably shift this to a dialog though.

Comment: @ctgScott np, im glad it helped :)

Comment: My mistake... I realized after continuing testing that the user may choose to perform the search a second time which requires me to set the ListView back to visible along with its contents.  I now have tried setting: mList.setAdapter(null); after the users makes a choice and that appears to be working as needed... any thoughts?

Comment: what about mList.setVisibility(View.Visible)? why do you set the adapter to null?

Comment: In order to reuse the search function and give the new list to the user I did setVisibility(View.VISIBLE).  However where I had placed that line of code returned to visible all of the prior list contents before the new search was performed/completed.  this was my mistake, of course... but it made me think... maybe it is better to set the adapter to null right away and let the adapter remain visible but empty.  Then have it re-filled after a new search (if one is actually called) instead of set invisible-perform search-set visible.  I don't know which is more efficient... just a guess.